# arraylist in java to sort data

Tags: java, arraylist

so i'm having issues making this work for me. what this code needs to do is have 3 different (string) fields that then sort them into alphabetical order i've had help before but it wont run on my netbeans. i am currently up to date with all updates as well.

heres the code i have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class test {
private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private List<LayoutOfScientist> scientistsNames = new ArrayList<LayoutOfScientist>();
private String name, field, idea;
private boolean continueLoop = true;
private int countTo3 = 0;

private void run() {
    while(countTo3<3&&continueLoop) {
        if(countTo3>0) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to add another scientist? (Y/N)");
        }

        if(countTo3 == 0 || scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the scientist's name:");
            name = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the scientist's field:");
            field = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the scientist's idea:");
            idea = scan.nextLine();
            scientistsNames.add(new LayoutOfScientist(name, field, idea));
        } else {
            continueLoop = false;
        }
        countTo3++;
    }

    scientistsNames.sort(Comparator.comparing(LayoutOfScientist::getScientistName));
    for(LayoutOfScientist lOS : scientistsNames) {
        System.out.println(lOS.getScientistName() + ", " + lOS.getScientistField() + ", " + lOS.getScientistIdea());
    }
}

private class LayoutOfScientist {
    private String scientistName, scientistField, scientistIdea;

    private LayoutOfScientist(String scientistName, String scientistField, String scientistIdea) {
        this.scientistName = scientistName;
        this.scientistField = scientistField;
        this.scientistIdea = scientistIdea;
    }

    public String getScientistName() {
        return scientistName;
    }

    public String getScientistField() {
        return scientistField;
    }

    public String getScientistIdea() {
        return scientistIdea;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().run();
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Exceptions help get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is `test` (lowercase t) and in your main method, you are calling `Test().run()`.
You need to rename your class to be Test and that should work. Or if your file is test you need to change `Test().run()` to `test().run()` instead of `public class test` to `public class test`. However, it is good programming practice to name a ClassLikeThis.

If your error is something else entirely, tell us what the error is.